# Streaming from obs to Nginx

Tags: nginx, video.js, rtmp, obs

I'm trying to stream from obs to nginx server. I'm using videojs as a player. In OBS Settings I'm using custom Streaming server and the url is  rtmp://localhost/live. this is the configuration file for nginx:

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;                     
                }
        }
}
```

and this is the html part:

```
<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" height="360" width="640" controls autoplay preload="none">
    <source src="rtmp://localhost/live" type="rtmp/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Is the flash plugin installed in the browser?

Comment: do you mean flash player ? I think it's installed. I already played other videos with videojs

Comment: other `rtmp://` videos?

Comment: No I can't play rtmp and I do have flash player.

Comment: Did you load the flash tech? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271187/how-to-play-rtmp-live-stream-using-videojs

Comment: no still not working I checked the link.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/DigiSkyOps/knife
this is a obs stream server

nginx/config

```
    rtmp {
  server {
    listen 1935;
    chunk_size 4000;
    application live {
      live on;
    }
    application hls {
        live on;
        hls on;
        hls_path /data/hls;
        hls_fragment 5s;
        hls_playlist_length 10s;
        hls_continuous on;
        hls_cleanup on;
        hls_nested on;
      }
    }
  }
```